# PDF to HTML with proper formatting

Tags: php, html, pdf, text

I am converting a PDF file to text `(HTML)`, the conversion is successful but it loses all ots conversion. Is there any way to maintain the proper formatting as it was originally in Pdf file?
I  got help for pdf to text from [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php)

Comment: Your [pdf2text.php](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php) is meant only as an attempt at *Reading the "clean" text from PDF with PHP,* i.e. the text without any formatting information (and it is even ignoring font encodings in content streams). Thus, if you want to really extract PDF content with its format, you should first study [the PDF specification ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and then be ready to invest some month's work into that project...

Answer (score 0):

Basically PDF is a document using fixed formatting where as html generally uses fluid formatting. You will not get an HTML document that looks exactly like the PDF did.

Additionally, some PDF features are not even supported in html.

Comment: then is there any way to create styles for the generated output i get from my code?

Comment: Theoretically yes, if you take the time to understand how styles are stored in PDF and how they would convert to css. I do believe that adobe publishes docs on the PDF file format.

Comment: will you please share any helpful link?

Comment: It appears that the standard is now part of ISO, which means you have to buy the document for about $250. [Adobe PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html). [ISO 32000-1](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=51502). You can however probably get away with older standard documents, there is a link to archives on the adobe page.

Comment: @datasage Actually Adobe publishes a copy of the ISO standard online, see my comment to the initial question, which *has been derived directly from the copyright ISO 32000-1 standard document [... and] is being made available [...] under agreement with ISO for those that do not need the official version containing the ISO logo and copyright notices. The technical material is identical between this version and the ISO Standard; the page and sections numbers are also preserved.* (Copyright Notice on page 2)